# D3 CSV Column Space Parsing

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

So I am working with D3

```
    d3.csv("data/food.csv", function (error, data) {
        temp = data;
        var foodCost = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            colleges.push([data[i].AverageCost, data[i].Quality]);
        }
```

And in the CSV im parsing, I have a column titled "Average Cost", but if I try to read it like i did above it is undefined, however if it's one word like "Quality" then it works perfectly. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `data[i].AverageCost` with `data[i]["Average Cost"]`